# In Javascript, how do I loop through objects inherited from a given constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In something like the following example, how would I go about looping over every object from the apple prototype?

```
function apple(id,name,color) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
}


apple1 = new apple(0,"Golden Delicious","Yellow");
myapple = new apple(1,"Mcintosh","Mixed");
anotherapple = new apple(2,"Bramley","Green");



/*
for each instance of apple {

  if (this one is "Green") { do something }

}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using capitalized name for constructor so the syntax highlighter gets it:

```
function Apple(name,color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.id = this.constructor.getId();
    this.constructor.instances[this.id] = this;
}

Apple.instances = {};

Apple.getId = (function(){
var i = 0;

    return function(){
    return i++;
    };

})();

/* ... */


var instance, key;

for( key in Apple.instances ) {
instance = Apple.instances[key];

    if( instance.color == "green" ) {
     delete Apple.instances[instance.id];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like static property that contains references to all instances. You'll add every instance there in the constructor:

```
function apple(id,name,color) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    apple.instances.push(this);
}
apple.instances = [];
```

Then, you can loop through `apple.instances`.